# Make facebook the ONLY / default login for devise canvas app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, facebook-canvas

I am making a Facebook canvas app hosted on heroku.
For authentication I am using devise gem with the omniauth-facebook gem.

Currently when the app is opened it asks you to "Sign In" with your email and password, or click the Sign In With Facebook button.

I wish to skip this page and when the user loads the app it should authenticate them automatically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your facebook app is asking for user permissions, and they have authorized it, the signed_request parameter that is passed to your rails app should contain the details you need. So what you can do is decode the parameter, and grab the facebook user id from the hash itself.

Try something like this:

```
class ApplicationController

  before_filter :inspect_signed_request

protected
  def base64_url_decode(input)
    input += ('=' * (4 - input.length % 4) % 4)
    Base64.decode64(input.tr('-_', '+/'))
  end    
  def inspect_signed_request
    encoded_sig, payload = params[:signed_request].split('.', 2)

    # decode the data
    sig = base64_url_decode(encoded_sig)
    data = JSON.parse(self.class.base64_url_decode(payload))
    raise data.inspect
  end
end
```

That will basically raise an exception, showing you the details of the signed request. Essentially, you can just parse it out as such, and check for the signed request FB ID value. If it's not there, you can add some code to redirect them to the login form instead.